# How to pass parameters to a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I try to do something like this:

ClassA:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 = int >
class ClassA {};
```

ClassB using ClassA as a Storage implementation:

```
template 
<
 typename T,
 template < typename = T, typename = int > class Storage = ClassA
>
class ClassB : public Storage<T> {};
```

Now I am able to create an instance of ClassB:

```
ClassB<double>          myClass;    // Ok, using ClassA (implicit) with <double,int> (implicit)
ClassB<double,ClassA>  myClass2;    // Ok, using ClassA (explicit) with <double,int> (implicit)
ClassB<double,ClassA<double,int>> myClass3; // Not ok, can't using ClassA (explicit) with <double,int> (explicit)
```

How can I parameterize the Storage (ClassA) for ClassB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put those in a separate parameter. `ClassA<double,int>` is a type already, so it cannot be used for the template template parameter.

```
template<typename T,
         template <typename, typename> class Storage = ClassA,
         typename StorageT1 = T,
         typename StorageT2 = int>
class ClassB : public Storage<StorageT1, StorageT2> {};

ClassB<double> myClass;
ClassB<double, ClassA> myClass2;
ClassB<double, ClassA, double, int> myClass3;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Isn't there any other solution? This looks like the template parameter 3. and 4 are for ClassB but they are to specialize ClassA

Comment: @jisaak: No. Either this, or make ClassA have default arguments and use `ClassB<double, ClassA<>>` in the second case.